# Error following Sylius Customizing Factories guide examples

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I'm just following the customization guide and I'm having problems with the customization example of the ProductFactoryInterface (http://docs.sylius.org/en/1.0/customization/factory.html)

I always get the same error:

> **Compile Error: Declaration of AppBundle\Factory\ProductFactory::createWithVariant():
>   Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ProductInterface must be compatible with
>   Sylius\Component\Product\Factory\ProductFactoryInterface::createWithVariant():
>   Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ProductInterface**

What am I doing wrong? This is my code:

```
namespace AppBundle\Factory;

use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ProductInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Product\Factory\ProductFactoryInterface;

class ProductFactory implements ProductFactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductFactoryInterface
     */
    private $decoratedFactory;

    /**
     * @param ProductFactoryInterface $factory
     */
    public function __construct(ProductFactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->decoratedFactory = $factory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createNew(): ProductInterface
    {
        return $this->decoratedFactory->createNew();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function createWithVariant(): ProductInterface
    {
        return $this->decoratedFactory->createWithVariant();
    }

    /**
     * @return ProductInterface
     */
    public function createDisabled(): ProductInterface
    {
        /** @var ProductInterface $product */
        $product = $this->decoratedFactory->createNew();

        $product->setEnabled(false);

        return $product;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change this use statement on top:

```
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ProductInterface;
```

With:

```
use Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ProductInterface;
```

Some of the interfaces have been changed just before the 1.0.0 release and it seems not all the documentation reflects this changes accordingly.